# writing a php script

Tags: php

how do you write a php script and execute that in a web page?suppose there is web page www.somepage.com and i want to find out a specific word in that page...i know you could search without a script since searching functionality is provided by the browser but how do someone write a script and find out that...i mean i need to know the method by which one can execute that script...please any help would be usefull..

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents("http://www.somepage.com/");

$find = strpos($html, "specific word");

?>
```

`$find` now contains the location of the word in the HTML.

Comment: i mean how do i execute that script??

Comment: You save it as `something.php`, upload it to your web host, then access `http://www.yoursite.com/something.php` in your browser.